# Convert reference to item to slice of length 1

Tags: rust, slice

I have a `&X`. How can I convert this to a `&[X]` of length 1? `std::slice::from_raw_parts` should work, but it is `unsafe`. Is there a safe function that I can use to do this conversion?

Comment: Unsafe code could be tricky. `fn ref_to_slice<T>(v: &T) -> &[T] { unsafe { ::std::slice::from_raw_parts(v as *const T, 1) } }` While this code could be fine, I am not entirely sure (panic safety - check, lifetimes are equal - check, no mutable aliasing - check, interior mutability - shouldn't be a problem, zero sized types - I couldn't see a problem, but not completely sure)